# Is there always at least one parse which accounts for all words cleanly using Phrase Structure Grammar trees?

Tags: grammar, syntax-trees, phrase-structure

A few small but related questions here. I'm looking at ways to define "sentence patterns", at least starting with English. That led me back to [phrase structure grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_structure_grammar), which have nice and fairly intuitive parse trees.

[image]

Main question that I've been wondering about is if all possible sentences can have an intuitive parse tree. I get that [sentences can have many parse trees](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/10958/can-a-sentence-have-different-parse-trees) depending on context and the way you look at the sentence. But even so, is it possible to always represent a sentence using this system?

Finally, *where do you **learn all the rules** for the symbols used in parse trees, and what word is considered what part of speech, sort of thing? I would like to more deeply explore complex sentence structures using this phrase structure grammar paradigm. To answer the question in my head about there maybe not being a valid parse tree for some sentences, or at least one that makes intuitive sense.*

*(Tangent question, wondering if there are open source projects which generate the data model for these [parse trees](https://medium.com/@datancoffee/showing-constituent-parse-trees-in-the-browser-1830976efcbf) given a sentence, I have spent an hour looking but will look some more).*

For clarity, I'm thinking what it would be like if you wrote down all the possible parse trees. Like for "[mary had a little lamb](https://elearning.cpp.edu/learning-objects/syntactic-tree-structures/assets/psr-instructions/)":

```
S > NP VP
NP > N
N > Mary
VP > V NP
V > had
NP > DET NP
DET > a
NP > AdjP N
AdjP > ADJ
ADJ > little
N > lamb
```

But wondering what can go into what, and generally the details of what's possible. So that's where I'm going for now.

Comment: "All the rules" is an entire field (syntax).

Comment: I at least found a list of [36 POS tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77456029/how-to-print-all-the-np-vp-noun-phrase-verb-phrase-and-sentence-structure-abb), but not the sentence-level tags.

Comment: All sentences can be parsed and so can utterances but then both can also be nonsense or gibberish. Everything depends on context, which you have to define...

Comment: [Abney 1995](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/abney95c.pdf) demonstrates that every written sentence is multiply ambiguous, so there are certainly parses. Whether they're the correct parses for a human language is another question.

Comment: It is not possible to assign a parse to every sentence that everyone finds to be intuitive. I don't think there is *any* sentence that has a universally-intuitive parse. If you're willing to settle for majority approval, and can define set who have voting rights, then maybe. Then there is the matter of how sentence trees relate to semantic interpretation.

Comment: You have two quite distinct parse trees in your question. The tree on the left is indeed a phrase structure tree, but the tree on the right is a dependency tree. If you are interested in intuitive parses, dependency trees are going to be a whole lot easier to produce.